# How to tag all points that fall below a diagonal line on a scatterplot

Tags: r

I would like a column in variabel df with a value of either TRUE or FALSE if the point falls below the diagonal line. The plot is just to illustrate the concept. I am quite stuck on this any help is appreciated.

```
# Test data
df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(1:100, 100, replace=FALSE),
  y = sample(1:100, 100, replace=FALSE))

library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y))
g + geom_point() +
    geom_abline(intercept = 25, slope = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: You want all points where 25 + x is more than y: `df$is_below <- 25 + df$x > df$y`. To clarify: you want all points `(x, y)` where the line (`25 + 1*x`) is above (`>`) the `y`-value.

Comment: Yes that is exactly it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (expanding further the suggestion of @Bas). The values you want are saved in variables `ye` which you can change to a logical too. Also you can change the definition of `ye`. In this case I added the numbers so that you can see as tags:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#Data
df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(1:100, 100, replace=FALSE),
  y = sample(1:100, 100, replace=FALSE))
#Create equation
df %>% mutate(ye=25+1*x,lab=ifelse(y<ye,y,NA)) -> df2
#Plot
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=x, y=y,label=lab))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 25, slope = 1)+
  geom_text(nudge_y = 2,check_overlap = T,size=2)
```

Output:
[image]